# Running Angular 2 app on VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I just created an Angular 2 app (HighlightMeDirective) in VSCode by following this plunker link [HighlightMeDirectivce](http://embed.plnkr.co/8uMBMinR6usJT4HE0QYA/)

On further research I found these are the steps to be followed for starting the app

1. Create a tasks.json file
2. Creating tsconfig.json file
3. Creating package.json file

Is this is the standard approach to be followed (in VSCode) or is there any simple approach to kick start the app (I don't want to use angular-seed)

Comment: If you want the best experience starting / developing an angular 2 app, I strongly recommend you look into the CLI. 
https://cli.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard approach and

1. **tasks.json** - this file is optional.
2. **tsconfig.json** - this file contains the information about how your
   compiler should compile your typescript into java script
3. **package.json** - this file contains information and description
   about your app and also contains the list of dependencies your
   project has.